# How to update a column based on condtions

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL Table and it looks like this.

```
+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| PONO     | ItemCode  | OrderQty | ReflectedQty | OtherStatus |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| PO787HZN | HKQSLUWKN | 30.00    | 30.00        | Posted      |
| PO787HZN | SORHFRBPJ | 40.00    | 40.00        | Posted      |
| PO787HZN | OP8XMREC0 | 50.00    | 50.00        | Posted      |
| PO787HZN | CPD5CGDZ3 | 60.00    | 60.00        | Posted      |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

and as time goes by the column `ReflectedQty` will be updated and it might look like this

```
    +----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
    | PONO     | ItemCode  | OrderQty | ReflectedQty | OtherStatus |
    +----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
    | PO787HZN | HKQSLUWKN | 30.00    | 20.00        | Posted      |
    | PO787HZN | SORHFRBPJ | 40.00    | 1.00         | Posted      |
    | PO787HZN | OP8XMREC0 | 50.00    | 5.00         | Posted      |
    | PO787HZN | CPD5CGDZ3 | 60.00    | 6.00         | Posted      |
    +----------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

My Question is how can i update the Column `OtherStatus` to `Partially Received` or `Fully Received` if Column `ReflectedQty` = `0.00`?

How can i achieve this using select command?

I will explain this by code(sample)

```
sqlcommand = select reflectedqty from table where reflectedqty = 0.00 and PONo = PO787HZN

if all ReflectedQty of PO787HZN = 0.00 then
'Update OtherStaus to = Fully Received
else
'Update OtherStaus to = Partially Received
end if
```

any other code accepted

TYSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query would look like below:

```
UPDATE your_table A
SET A.ReflectedQty = A.ReflectedQty - @valueToBeDeducted,
 A.OtherStatus =
                IF (
                        (A.ReflectedQty - @valueToBeDeducted) <= 0,
                        'Fully Receieved',
                        'Partially Receieved'
                )
WHERE...
```

<sub>`valueToBeDeducted` is an input parameter</sub>

**And if you want to update all at a time:**

```
UPDATE your_table A
SET A.OtherStatus =
IF (
    A.ReflectedQty <= 0,
    'Fully Receieved',
    'Partially Receieved'
)
WHERE <your_condtion_here>
```

Comment: what is the valuetobededucted?

Comment: I guessed you passed this as input while there's a deduction from `ReflectedQty`. In a word, it's an input parameter. By the way, do you want to update all the rows at a time? Then look at the second query

Comment: TYSM for the help sir :) I did some update with the 2nd code becuase its the one that worked for me. TYSM

Comment: You are welcome sir. Glad to hear that you modified the query to make it run. Means you understood it. :)

Comment: Yes I did use the second one and i add `where PONo = 'PO787HZN` at the end and it worked TYSM

Comment: Actually I intended to provide the skeleton so that you can work with it. (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can update the fields in update query itself check below one.

```
update yourtable set OtherStaus =(if(ReflectedQty='0.00' and PONO='PO787HZN','Fully Received','Partially Received'));
```

based on your condition have written the sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Code: you would need to do similar in MySql

```
UPDATE Table T1 
SET 
OtherStatus = CASE 
                 WHEN T2.RFQ = 0 THEN 'Fully Received'
                 ELSE 'Partially Received'
              END
FROM (
    SELECT PONO, SUM(ReflectedQty) RFQ GROUP BY PONO 
     ) T2 
INNER JOIN ON T2.PONO = T1.PONO
```